# What is maximum number of statements in main function?

Tags: c, syntax

What is the maximum number of statements that the main function or any other function can handle ?
What is the limit of characters of statement ?

Comment: The standard doesn't say anything about limits. Why is this important ?

Comment: There isn't a practical limit. However, it is possible that your program could eventually be too big to fit on your target device. However, the size of the program isn't tied to the length of your statements.

Comment: While I would not say this is a bad question, but you are expected to show some research effort. What did you try searching before asking this question?

Comment: @MichaelWalz The C spec has a couple pages on limits "5.2.4 Environmental limits" including ones (or lack of them) that relate to this post.

Answer (score 5):

According to the standard document, `C11`, chapter 5.2.4.1, "Translation limits" (under "Environmental limits") there's **no specified limit** on `number of statements` in `main()` or any other function, or in a translation unit.

You're only limited by your <del>imagination</del> *working environment* (*operating system, compiler configuration, target platform etc.*).

Comment: @EugeneSh. or, [be afraid.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/)

Answer (score 1):

C standard doesn't specify any translation limits (usually it specifies lower limits, but not for this) for *number of statements*.
So, this is unspecified and may differ on different platforms.

[GCC's documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-limits.html), although not directly on *number of statements*, states a relevant information on the *size* of the source files:

> Maximum size of a source file.
>
> The standard does not specify any lower limit on the maximum size of a
>   source file. GNU cpp maps files into memory, so it is limited by the
>   available address space. This is generally at least two gigabytes.
>   Depending on the operating system, the size of physical memory may or
>   may not be a limitation.

Unless, this is of theoritical interest, this *should* never an issue in practive. 
Typical source files (that you expect to be read and understood by fellow programmers) are much smaller than that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit of statements, but don't write all your code in the main it might get...quite ugly. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no specified limit, you can not go on writing an arbitrarily large routine. Just keep in mind that this routine has to be compiled into assembly. These assembly instructions must fit on the storage device / memory.